# Volume or directory shared between services and runner container in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm specifically trying to get files from services (docker containers) in a Gitlab CI job to the runner container. *I could provide more details on exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to keep this question fairly generic and platform/language agnostic.

Essentially I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image: customselfhostedimage-redacted

services:
  - postgres:latest
  - selenium/standalone-chrome

...
```

There are files being downloaded in one of the service containers (selenium) which I need to gain access to from the main container being run by the Gitlab runner. Unfortunately I can not seem to find any method to create a volume mount or share of some sort between service containers and the host **(※ NOTE: This was not true, see accepted answer.)**. Adding commands to specifically copy files from within service containers is also not an option for me. I'm aware of multiple issues requesting such functionality, such as this one:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3207

The existence of these open issues indicates to me there is not currently a solution.

I have tried to specify volumes in config.toml as has been in comments in various Gitlab CI issues related to this subject, but this does not seem to create volume mounts on *service* containers?

Is there any way to create volume mounts inside service containers accessible to the runner/runner container, or if not is there any simple solution to make files accessible from (and possibly between) service containers?

※ NOTE: This is NOT a docker-compose question, and it is NOT a docker-in-docker question.

Comment: Side note I wanted to keep out of the main question: Selenium specifically recommends mounting a volume for this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#mounting-volumes-to-retrieve-downloaded-files - if the assumptions in my question are correct this is not currently possible?

Comment: What is your task doing? And how does your task know when to grab the files? 
Seems like you should convert the selenium service to a task. And store the file as an artifact in gitlab. So you can fetch that artifact in another task.

Comment: `This is NOT a docker-compose question, and it is NOT a docker-in-docker question` So  you know that you can run docker-in-docker image from gitlab-ci and run your docker-compose with the stuff you want to execute in it?

Comment: @Leroy In this particular case I'm running rails specs with Capybara, and some of those involve downloading files and checking the contents of the files. But I didn't want to make this a question specifically about that, nor did I want a solution specifically for that, as I can imagine other situations where having access to files within a service container or having volumes shared between containers would be handy - so I'm looking for more of a general solution.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I am aware of that, and I do not want to do that, which is why I specifically noted it is not a docker-in-docker question. If you must know: The reason why is, in our situation, docker-in-docker adds unneeded complexity and the system we are running on has some limitations which inhibit the functionality of docker-in-docker builds.

Comment: Note: as @KamilCuk has mentioned; docker-in-docker may be workaround for some people looking for a solution to this same question. Just for me and my team in this particular situation it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you self-host your runners, you can add volumes to the runner configuration, which applies to services and job containers alike.

Per [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#example-2-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> GitLab Runner 11.11 and later [mount the host directory](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/1261) for the defined [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) as well.

For example:

```
[runners.docker]
  # ...
  volumes = ["/path/to/bind/from/host:/path/to/bind/in/container:rw"]
```

This path will be available both in the job as well as in containers defined in `services:`. But keep in mind that the data (and changes) are available and persisted across all jobs that use this runner.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer does in fact appear to be the correct answer (I will edit my initial question to note my assumption was wrong).

In my particular situation I think there's a permission issue - but upon re-investigating the volume is in fact mounted just as you say (it's just not *accessible* in the service containers for me, which is likely a different issue).